# EF - Return multiple results sets from single query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Using entity framework and linq, I am looking to return 3 different result sets from 3 different tables in the database. These tables contain essentially lookup values that populate the view models select list. At the moment I have to make 3 separate calls to the database to retrieve each list of items. Can I reduce this down to a single call?

I have already tried the following, which didn't work:

```
var lists = await (from d in dbContext.Durations
                from t in dbContext.Types
                from p in dbContext.Platforms
                select {
                    Durations = d,
                    Types = t,
                    Platforms = p
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What is the relation between Duration, Type and Platform? I mean which table contain which foreign key?

Comment: @CodeNotFound there is no relationship between them. Each table contains non related look up values, that I use to populate drop down lists on the view.

Comment: Then tree different queries is really needed. No way.

Comment: If you really need one database roundtrip you could look at future queries of [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended).

Comment: @GertArnold That's a really interesting set of extensions. Would you recommend using the library? You say "If you really need" like it's a last resort type of scenario? Cheers

Comment: Well, I can't tell how badly you need to reduce the number of roundtrips. I wouldn't jump through these hoops too quickly. It introduces a dependency to a third-party library that *currently* has a good reputation. But in the future...?

Comment: @GertArnold hmm you've definitely given me something to think about. I think I'm in a phase of premature optimisation at the moment, rather than a necessity to reduce calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the three tables `Duration`, `Types` and `Platforms` are not related in any way:

Think about how a SQL query with one single `SELECT` statement could look like to query all three tables. You will not find one that fits your needs.

So, creating three distinct queries is absolutely reasonable in that case. What you can and should do though, is, use the same `dbContext` instance for the three queries.

```
var durationsList = await dbContext.Durations.ToListAsync();
var typesList = await dbContext.Types.ToListAsync();
var platformsList = await dbContext.Platforms.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Yeah this essentially what I'm already doing. I guess I'm just trying to optimise the request by reducing calls to the database. Maybe I shouldn't worry about this, as clearly there is no simple solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If reducing database roundtrips is what you're after,
you can use Future() (part of Z.EntityFramework.Plus) to batch your requests

```
var durationsFuture = dbContext.Durations.Future();
var typesFuture = dbContext.Types.Future();
var platformsFuture = dbContext.Platforms.Future();

var durationsList = durationsFuture.ToList(); // this line will retrieve all 3 collections
var typesList = typesFuture.ToList();
var platformsList = platformsFuture.ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

logically, you should make 3 separate queries to SQL.
there is absolutely nothing wrong with making those 3 calls to populate the unrelated lookup vaues.

but if you absolutely want to avoid 3 DB calls (equivalent of a SPROC having 3 SELECT statements)

CAUTION: this is a cartesian product, for all 3 tables.

can you try this following LINQ query.. we are trying to get the cartesian product of these 3 tables (true condition) and project out the 3 tables without any relation to each other.

```
var lists = await dbContext.Durations.Join(dbContext.Types, d => true, t => true, 
                                           (d, t) => new { d, t })
                                     .Join(dbContext.Platforms, dt => true, p => true, 
                                           (dt, p) => new 
                                                     { 
                                                      Duration = dt.d, 
                                                      Type = dt.t, 
                                                      Platform = p
                                                     })
                                     .Distinct()
                                     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: The answer is valid, but a word of warning would be nice before blindly executing this query. I think it was not the OPs intent to create the cartesian product. This might should be stated in the answer.

Comment: This is bad. And it isn't correct. `dt.d` isn't a collection (Durations), it is *one* `Duration`.

Comment: @user1384848 i mentioned the cartesian part of it in the answer.. stressing it again, thanks.

Comment: @GertArnold i agree that this should not be done. hence, we recommend the good practice.. but the question specifically is: 'At the moment I have to make 3 separate calls to the database to retrieve each list of items. Can I reduce this down to a single call?' and that is what i am trying to help with. (after mentioning clearly that it is okay to make 3 separate calls) and i fixed the dt.T part.. thanks for that.

Comment: My downvote stands. Not only is a cartesian product a potential performance killer, but you also end up with `a * b * c` unique combinations that `Distinct` doesn't reduce. Each `Duration` occurs `b * c` times in the result. I don't mind showing downsides of *viable* alternatives. But this solution shouldn't even be considered.

Comment: @GertArnold i agree with the cartesian downside. thank you again for reiterating that.

Comment: @stoward94 please evaluate your record-count and make an informed call on 3 DB calls vs. 1 call which gets a*b*c records.. thanks..